# Does correlating file contents to find moves work?

Tags: algorithm

I'm curious about detecting file changes for something like a folder sync program.

If a file's contents have changed but its path and name is the same, it is trivial to detect.

If the contents are identical, but the file has been moved, it is still possible to detect that by doing something like an all-by-all comparison.

What if a file's contents have changed slightly *and* it has moved? Is there a reliable way of detecting that instead of treating this as separate file deletion and creation events?

**EDIT:** After seeing the answer by Tobias, I realized that I should clarify and say that I am talking about synchronizing a large amount of data (100s of GB, 10,000s of files, many of them binary) in a reasonable amount of time (seconds on an average personal computer).

Comment: You could compare two files either from the beginning or the end and say that if the bytes are the same up to some threshold, it's the same file that got both changed and renamed, but this is probably still going to be prohibitively expensive for, say, 10,000 files. Why not simply say that if it's both moved and changed, it's not the same file?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Well, Tobias's suggestion of only doing the content scan for files that appear to be removed would drastically reduce the search space. However, the use case is to allow the users to quickly decide "yeah I remember moving and changing that file" vs. "this file was deleted and a similar file was created elsewhere? that sounds weird, I need to investigate in detail"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compare the content of the files with their [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). So you can detect wether a file has been slightly changed and moved (if you compare it all-by-all).

A pseudocode algorithm (from Wikipedia) could look like this:

```
// len_s and len_t are the number of characters in string s and t respectively
int LevenshteinDistance(const char *s, int len_s, const char *t, int len_t)
{ 
  int cost;

  /* base case: empty strings */
  if (len_s == 0) return len_t;
  if (len_t == 0) return len_s;

  /* test if last characters of the strings match */
  if (s[len_s-1] == t[len_t-1])
      cost = 0;
  else
      cost = 1;

  /* return minimum of delete char from s, delete char from t, and delete char from both */
  return minimum(LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s - 1, t, len_t    ) + 1,
                 LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s    , t, len_t - 1) + 1,
                 LevenshteinDistance(s, len_s - 1, t, len_t - 1) + cost);
}
```

It could be done even faster if you just compare to files that were removed, so you don't need to compare the new file to every file in the filesystem.

Comment: I think your last paragraph is a pretty good idea, but would Levenshtein work for files that are not text? I suppose you could take byte-wise distance instead of char-wise, and you could make it independent of file size by sampling a constant number of random positions instead of the whole file. However isn't it the case that for example changing 1 pixel in a JPEG can massively alter the file contents?

Comment: For most binary files the Levenshein distance will not work. If you change 1 pixel in an image (in almost every image type; jpg, png, ...) it will always change the complete file, because the images (and many other binary files) get compressed like a zip file. So byte-wise distances will probably not work for most types. But there are tools that can be used for many datatypes. E.g. for images you could load the image to the memory and check the differences in every pixel...

Comment: ... (or maybe have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719545/are-there-any-tools-that-can-do-the-equivalent-of-a-git-diff-with-images-to-s)). You could also try do find something like git-diff tools that check whether binary files are equal. I think there are some for e.g. Microsoft-office or libre-office files and maybe also for images.